# Logcat for application running on actual device

Tags: android, logging

Is there any way to see logcat for application that is running on actual device?
I can see logcat for emulator. While running the application itself I selected my cellphone to run the application. Application gets installed that way, but I cant see logcat for it. 
Please help....

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select perspective view in eclipse and choose DDMS. Inside DDMS, you see the list of all the running devices and now you can switch to your device and see its log.